# Endomorphism of $\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$ such that $ f({}^t M)={}^t f(M)$

Tags: linear-algebra

I and a friend are trying to find all endomorphisms $f$ of $\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$ such that $f({}^t M)={}^t f(M)$ for all $M$. We believe they are of the form $M\mapsto\lambda M+\mu {}^t M$ for a fixed $(\lambda,\mu)\in\mathbb{R}^2$. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: How about $M\mapsto \lambda M + \mu\,{}^t\!M$?

Comment: Yes you are right, the set of all such endomorphisms is a vector space.

Comment: How about the map reversing the order of columns and rows of a matrix? $(a_{ij}) \mapsto (a_{n-i+1,n-j+1})$?

Comment: How about $M \mapsto \mathrm{Tr}(M) S$ where $S$ is any symmetric matrix ?

Comment: It seems there are more solutions than I excepted, this would mean there are too much solutions to find all of them in a simple way...

Comment: @Tuvasbien I think there is a lot of solutions, but maybe we can still find all of them. Because it is a vector space, finding a basis would be sufficient to describe all of them.

Comment: This is indeed a subspace of the $n^4$-dimensional vector space $V=\operatorname{End}(\mathcal M_n(\mathbb R))$. It is the kernel of the endomorphism $f\mapsto f\circ T-T\circ f$ on $V$, where $T(M)={}^t\!M$. Maybe finding rank or nullity of this would be start.

Comment: Yes since it has a finite dimension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f$ be a linear endomorphism on $M_n(\mathbb R)$. Then
$$
f(M^T)=f(M)^T\quad\forall M\tag{1}
$$
if and only if
$$
f(M)=\frac12\left(g(M)+g(M^T)^T\right)\quad\forall M\tag{2}
$$
for some endomorphism $g$.

Given $g$, it is straightforward to verify $(1)$ when $f$ is defined by $(2)$. Conversely, given any $f$ that satisfies $(1)$, condition $(2)$ is satisfied by taking $g=f$.

Alternatively, note that $(1)$ is satisfied if and only if $f$ preserves both symmetric and skew-symmetric matrices. Hence such an $f$ takes the form of $f(M)=h\left(\frac{M+M^T}{2}\right)+k\left(\frac{M-M^T}{2}\right)$ where $h$ is an endomorphism defined on the space $\mathcal H_n$ of all symmetric matrices and $k$ is an endomorphism defined on the space $\mathcal K_n$ of all skew-symmetric matrices. Therefore the dimension of the space of all such $f$s is
$$
\dim\operatorname{End}(\mathcal H_n)+\dim\operatorname{End}(\mathcal K_n)
=\left[\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right]^2+\left[\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\right]^2
=\frac{n^2(n^2+1)}{2}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

First, consider a basis of the space $\mathcal{M}_n$. For example, the $n^2$ elementary matrices $e_{ij}$ which are all zero's except a $1$ in the $(i,j)$ spot. An element $f \in \mathrm{End}(\mathcal{M}_n)$ is determined by where it sends each $e_{ij}$. Call these $M_{ij}$, so that $f(e_{ij}) = M_{ij}$. Then for an arbitrary matrix $A$ with entries $a_{ij}$, you have
$$ f(A) = \sum_{i,j} a_{ij} M_{ij} $$

Now, you want to consider when $f$ commutes with the transpose operation. Consider this in the special case of the basis elements $e_{ij}$. Notice that ${}^te_{ij} = e_{ji}$, so the condition becomes :

$$
\begin {align*}
f({}^te_{ij}) &= {}^tf(e_{ij}) \\
f(e_{ji}) &= {}^tM_{ij} \\
M_{ji} &= {}^tM_{ij}
\end {align*}
$$

Comment: This shows that $f$ fits if and only if $f({}^t e_{i,j})={}^tf(e_{i,j})$ and thus the vector space of all such endomorphisms is the one generated by the $f_{i,j,A}$ such that $f_{i,j,A}(e_{i,j})=A$, $f_{i,j,A}(e_{j,i})={}^t A$ and $f_{i,j,A}(e_{k,l})=0$ for $(k,l)\notin\{(i,j),(j,i)\}$. This is maybe the nicest form of the solutions. The dimension of this vector space is thus $$\sum_{i<j}n^2+\sum_{i=1}^n n^2=\frac{n^3(n-1)}{2}$$

Comment: @Tuvasbien No. For $i<j$, $M_{ij}$ can be chosen freely, but for $i=j$, $M_{ij}$ must be symmetric. Therefore the dimension is $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\times n^2+n\times\frac{n(n+1)}{2}=\frac{n^2}{2}[n(n-1)+(n+1)]=\frac{n^2(n^2+1)}{2}$.